# How to change accessibility traits language?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

How can we change accessibility traits language for voice over based on the app language not the iPhone language.

Eg. My device language is in english but for app user can select language, based on user selected language app will be updated. But for accessibility traits, it is picking the default iPhone language .

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `accessibilityLanguage` property for your elements.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615192-accessibilitylanguage